# Why does converting a m4a/wma to wav result in a ridiculously high bitrate file?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, conversion, bitrate

If I use the simple command `ffmpeg -i file.m4a file.wav`, the resulting file invariably seems to have a bitrate of around 750kbit/s (resulting in a 500mb file from a 100mb one my case).

I've already tried [this](https://superuser.com/a/675647/538175) answer (tldr: `ffmpeg -i song.mp3 -acodec pcm_u8 -ar 22050 song.wav`), among others, but the bitrate always turns out to be ridiculously large.

I like my files to be in wav format so that I can easily burn a CD from the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wav` is simply uncompressed audio. Its bitrate is simply the size that audio would be without some smart algorithm reducing the size using psychoacoustic modelling.

Your files are probably 16-bit 44.1kHz audio. that will end up at 16-bit (2 bytes) x dual channel (2) x 44.1kHz which will give a bitrate of about 1.44Mbit/s. Single channel audio would be half that at 720kBit/s, and similarly reducing 44.1kHz to 22.05kHz keeping 16 bit sampling will again be 720kBit/s.

Without knowing what your goal is, then I'd suggest you leave the files in their original format, or use an actual compressed output such as `flac`.

Answer (score 1):

WAVs have uncompressed audio, so the file size is a linear function of duration, irrespective of content.

Formula is `sample depth x sampling rate x channel count x duration (in seconds)`.